# Javascript - Remove the focus from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, keyup

I have an input that display a message for an invalid email format. This message disappear when the format is respected.

```
$('#id_email.form-control').keyup(function(){
$('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
var inputVal = $(this).val();
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
  $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="error error-keyup-email">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
}
});
```

The code works very good. That's exactly what I wanted.

**Problem :** When I select an email that I have already saved by the browser (Normally it saves email or pseudo for the user). When I don't type my email and I select my email instead, the message still stays under the input, even if it's a correct email format.

Do you have an idea ?

I can give you more details if you want and thank you for taking time on my problem :)

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Try using `input` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#id_email.form-control').on('input', function(){
$('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
var inputVal = $(this).val();
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
  $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="error error-keyup-email">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
}
});
```

***keyup*** only fires once the key is pressed. ***input*** fires immediately when the value changes

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when using autofill from the browser, you have to detect it somehow. Unfortunately input's change event is not triggered in that case.

A possible solution might be to traverse all the input fields onload and check if they are filled in

Answer (score 0):

//remove error span in else

```
$('#id_email.form-control').keyup(function(){
    $('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
      $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="error error-keyup-email">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
    }
  else{
      $('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use input change event which called auto when focus is lost

```
$('#id_email.form-control').change(function(){

});
```